# Erro 404 ao carregar página. Como resolver?

Tags: javascript, load

O problema é que quando recarrego página, o sistema retorna o erro `404` neste arquivo `js/theme.min.js`

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Esse arquivo existe? No chrome, aperta F12, vai em Network, atualiza a página clica em cima da requisição que ta com erro e vê o caminho

Comment: Sim, tem presente na página porém quando executo teste de desempenho após certa quantia de usuários começa a dar error 404